# European Option Delta derivation

Tags: probability, derivatives, finance

With the **Black-Scholes** formula for a call option:

$$P= S e^{-\delta T } \Phi(d_{1}) - K e^{-rT} \Phi(d_{2}) $$

With $d_{1}$ and $d_{2}$ as:

$$ d1 = \frac{\ln\left(\frac{S}{K}\right) + \left(r - \delta + \frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)T}{\sigma \sqrt{T}} $$

$$ d2 = d1 - \sigma \sqrt{T} $$

I derived $\frac{\partial P}{\partial S}$ and ended up with this:

$$   \Delta = e^{-\delta T} \Phi(d_{1}) + \frac{S e^{-\delta T} \phi(d_{1})- K e^{-r T} \phi(d_{2})  }{S \sigma \sqrt{T}}             $$

I know the formula for delta is: $\Delta= e^{-\delta T} \Phi(d_{1})$  so that means the right side of the sum equals zero. Also in the Book: **"Derivatives Markets - Mc Donald"** says it can be shown that:

$$ S e^{-\delta T} \phi(d_{1})= K e^{-r T} \phi(d_{2})  $$

This is where i cant follow up, i dont see how they are equal and i havent found any book with this proof. I know its equal, but why?

Comment: By definition of $d_1$ in the derivation of the BS formula that term you want to be zero *is* zero. Plug $d_1$ in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Too long for a comment.

Just complete the square. You know that
$$
\phi(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \, \exp\left\{ -\frac12 x^2\right\}
$$
and
$$
d_1 = \frac{ \log S_t/K + (r - \delta + \frac12 \sigma^2)T }{ \sigma\sqrt T}, \quad d_2 = d_1 - \sigma \sqrt T
$$
It follows then quite easily that
$$
Se^{-\delta T} \phi (d_1) = Ke^{-r T} \phi (d_2)
$$

Comment: thx, couldnt manage to get $\phi(d_{1}) \text{ from } \phi(d_{2})$